# What's the meaning of "the grammatical logic was as much in need of correction"?

Tags: meaning, grammar, meaning-in-context, sentence-construction

- Firstly, I don't know the meaning of "**grammatical logic**".
- Secondly, I don't understand the relationship between "grammatical logic" and "correction".

Could you please explain it to me?

The text is here:

> None of my professors at BYU had examined my writing the way
>   Professor Steinberg did. No comma, no period, no adjective or adverb was
>   beneath his interest. He made no distinction between grammar and
>   content, between form and substance. A poorly written sentence was a
>   poorly conceived idea, and in his view **the grammatical logic was as much
>   in need of correction**. “Tell me,” he would say, “why have you placed this
>   comma here? What relationship between these phrases are you hoping to
>   establish?” When I gave my explanation sometimes he would say, “Quite
>   right,” and other times he would correct me with lengthy explanations of
>   syntax.

*Educated* by Tara Westover

Comment: I think you can understand **logic** there to mean **rationale** (i.e. for his recommendations and criticisms relating to syntax, punctuation, and phrasing).   Your second question is about a sentence which Professor Steinberg would probably have circled.  :-)    The author doesn't mean to say **correction** but **attention**.  The phrasing of an idea is not less important than the idea itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. *grammatical logic* – Prof. Steinberg "made no distinction between grammar and content". That is, he quite properly felt that the logical meaning of a proposition can only be discerned through its form. Grammar itself possesses a 'logic'—a formal structure through which meaning is discerned.
2. The author has left it to the reader to infer the complement of the comparative construction: *the grammatical logic was as much in need of correction **as the logic of the idea***. "Poor writing reflects a poorly conceived idea", and a writer refines and corrects her ideas by refining and correcting her grammar.
3. *No comma [...] was beneath his interest* means "No comma [...] was too trivial for him to take into consideration", and his fastening on a particular comma is an example of this.